# angular-mocks giving me a module error when testing a component

Tags: angularjs, jestjs

I'm receiving the following error when trying to test a component with angularJS. This component is part of a library I've created with this language and uses Jest instead of Jasmine.

```
      TypeError: angular_1.default.mock.module is not a function

   6 | describe('Badge', () => {
   7 |   beforeEach(() => {
>  8 |     angular.mock.module(['myApp.components.quoteCard']);
     |                  ^
   9 |   });
  10 |   it('renders badge', () => {
  11 |     render(`
```

This is the test code following the specifities:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks';
import { render, screen } from 'angularjs-testing-library';
import './quote-card';

describe('Badge', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module(['myApp.components.quoteCard']);
  });
  it('renders badge', () => {
    render(`
      <quote-card-component
        content="content"
        author="author"
      ></quote-card-component>
      `);

    expect(screen.getByText(`content`)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

If someone knows how to solve this, it would be great. Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

Angular mocks works only with Jasmine or Mocha. Theres a strict condition inside the library. So you need to setup a global variable before running your tests.
For example

```
global.mocha = true;
```